# Turning foreach statements into a function, issue

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach, multidimensional-array

I have this code (below) working just fine, however whenever I try to 'wrap' it in a function eg. `function systemLoop($series) { ... }` I get nothing but uber fail.

I'm new to PHP (and coding at this level) and multidimensional arrays. So getting it to work as a function is even more alien to me. However since I have a "few" system series arrays to go through I thought to have it in a function could be a better solution. So all I have to do is call `systemLoop("hyper"); systemLoop("business");`

Please can you help? Am I doing the right thing by trying to turn it into a function? If am on the right step is there a possible step i'm excluding to making the function work as intended?

```
$series = "super";  
foreach ( $systems[$series] as $names => $name ) {
    echo "<ul>";
    if (is_array($name)){
        echo "<h2>$names => $name</h2>";

        foreach( $systems[$series][$names] as $details => $detail ){
            if (is_array($detail)){}else{
                echo "<h3>$details => $detail</h3>";
            }
        }

        foreach( $systems[$series][$names]['components'] as $components => $component ){
            if(is_array($component)){

                foreach( $systems[$series][$names]['components']['cpu'] as $part => $specs ){
                    echo "<li>cpu $part => $specs</li>";
                }//ends foreach

            }else{
                echo "<li>$components => $component</li>";
            }//ends if is_array
        }// ends foreach
    }else{
        echo "<li>$name</li>";
    }//ends if is_array
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "<hr/>";
}//ends foreach
```

Comment: `$systems[$series][$names]` should be replaced with `$name` throughout your foreach loop.

Comment: "nothing but uber fail" doesn't really tell us what the problem is.  What, specifically, is the problem/symptom?

Comment: @cbuckley - If i do, the foreach's don't run as intended.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm trying to get this code to work as a function. If I wrap it, nothing happens. I don't know if there's a step i'm missing. I just cannot find the solution.

Comment: If you wrap up the logic in a function, do you pass the `$systems` variable in too, or make it global? Have a look at [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: @cbuckley Thank you. I never knew variable scopes existed... Or kn fact they were required in a function.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to run before you learn to crawl :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your problem with wrapping it in a function comes from not passing the $systems variable, which you can do either as a global or a parameter in the function call. I'll show the 2 examples here:

Passing $systems as a parameter:

```
function systemLoop($series, $systems){
```

Which you would call like this:

```
systemLoop('super', $systems);
```

Or passing $systems as a global:

```
function systemLoop($series){
    global $systems;
```

Then you would call the function like this:

```
systemLoop('super');
```

From what it sounds like the problem might be, either way should fix the problem you're having.

Comment: Adding the $systems global variable worked a treat. I knew it was a simple thing I was missing. Thank you very much :).

Comment: I'd advise against the global in favor of passing the value in. It will make it easier to "follow the data" if you encounter bugs, as well as make it clear when $systems is being modified.

Comment: @Fleep Would passing the value in be like, "systemLoop($series, $systems)"? For now adding the global works perfectly and how I hoped it would. I'm not disagreeing, I just don't know what passing the value in is...

Comment: Yes, passing the value - passing the value as a parameter - is shown in my first example.